# Amplitude value after a Discrete-Time integration calculation?

Tags: integration, simulink

I am using Matlab block [*Discrete-Time
Integrator*](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/discretetimeintegrator.html) on Simulink and I would like to know in advance, what  output of that block regarding to its amplitude and the current sampling frequency would be.

For instance, I am setting as input  a $$ {\tt Reference} (t) = A \sin(\omega t)$$ where $ A = 0.4$ and $\omega = 2\pi\cdot 2KHz$, the outcome of  *Discrete-Time
Integrator* is my ${\tt Reference} (t)$ integrated a *cosine* function as expected  $$ve[n] = -B \cos[\Omega n]$$ with $B=2.55*10^4$

[image]

However, as shown in the picture  the amplitude $B$ is quite large, which puzzles me. I am aware that the integrator scales the output with $K T_s$, being my $f_s = 200MHz$. So I was wondering whether or not there is an expression that allows me know that scale factor in the amplitude that is happening after the integration, I am aware that is related to my sampling time but I cannot figure out how or what is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out coming back to basic maths, I  was making a mistake when integrating my *sin* function that Matlab block wasn't doing, I was missing behind the $\omega$ variable

$$ve[n] = -B \cdot \cos[\Omega\cdot n] = \int A\sin(\omega\cdot t) = (A/\omega)(-\cos(\omega\cdot t)) + Const$$ $$\mathbf {B = (A/\omega) }$$